# WebGrid sorting not working

Tags: c#, razor, webgrid

I am using WebGrid to show a table of data from my database. 
This table has a column with quantities. 
I hope someone can tell me why this grid isn't sorting?

```
@{  
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(
        source: Model,
        rowsPerPage: 10,
        canPage: true,
        canSort: false,
        ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid",
        ajaxUpdateCallback: "initGrid",
        sortFieldName: "Qty_containers",
        sortDirectionFieldName: "ASC"
    );
}

    <div id="grid" class="ajax">
            @grid.GetHtml(
                tableStyle: "border", headerStyle: "red",
                columns: grid.Columns(
                grid.Column(columnName: "Haulier", 
header: ResourceContext.Get("Model.ShortTerm.Haulier")),
                grid.Column(columnName: "ETA_vessel", 
header: ResourceContext.Get("Model.ShortTerm.ETA_vessel"), format:
                    @<text>
                        @item.ETA_vessel.ToShortDateString()
                    </text>),
                grid.Column(columnName: "Container_length", header: ResourceContext.Get("Model.ShortTerm.Container_length"), format:
                    @<text>
                            @{string length = item.Container_length.ToString();
                              if(length.Equals("_blank_")){
                                length = "";
                              }
                              else if(length.Equals("_x0032_0_ft")){
                                length = "20 ft"; 
                              }
                              else{
                                length = "30 ft";
                              }
                             }
                            @length
                    </text>),
                grid.Column(columnName: "Qty_containers", header: ResourceContext.Get("Model.ShortTerm.Qty_containers"), canSort: true)
                )
            ) 
        </div>
```

[image: My grid]

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems with the "WebGrid". Try this in your collection:

```
objectModel.OrderByDescending(d => d.Qty_containers);
```

Comment: Ok this works, but there is a webgrid sorting function.. That has to work too :)

Answer (score 0):

Change this property and it should work `canSort: true`. In your code "canSort" is set to "False"